# implication of metadata being in XML?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

what is the implication of metadata being represented in XML? how is this useful to me as a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of using the XML markup language to represent system metadata doesn't really have any direct implications in and of itself.

The metadata XML files can be useful to a developer in that if you know what tags and values to change, it can save a lot of time that would otherwise be spent clicking around in the ui. There is some overhead in working with metadata files since you need to retrieve the metadata, make changes, and then deploy them back into salesforce, but it can be really helpful if you need to create a lot of similar fields, or you have a similar task where copy-paste can replace dozens of clicks.